# System Error: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - ogre-meshviewer

Tags: 16.04, snap, opengl

Ogre 1.11.6

```
$ locate libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0


$ ogre-meshviewer athene.mesh
...
Unregistering ResourceManager for type HighLevelGpuProgram
Unregistering ResourceManager for type Material
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/ogre-meshviewer/224/bin/ogre_mesh_viewer.py", line 380, in <module>
    app.initApp()
RuntimeError: InternalErrorException: Could not load dynamic library /snap/ogre-meshviewer/224/usr/lib/OGRE/RenderSystem_GL.  System Error: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in DynLib::load at /build/ogre-meshviewer/parts/ogre/src/OgreMain/src/OgreDynLib.cpp (line 117)


$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS \n \l
```

https://github.com/OGRECave/ogre-meshviewer

How to solve this error?

Comment: What I would do in such situation is run the command you are trying to run with strace - so something like "strace ogre-meshviewer". You will see lot of output, like a lot ... but you should look for open and read event. This means "strace -e trace=open,read ogre-meshviewer". In the output you should find where exactly is the software looking for library.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. @RiddleMeThis

Comment: This shouldn't happen in a snap package - snaps are self contained and should include all necessary libraries. Seems like a bug in packaging.